# Calling Python subprocess with variable in for loop

Tags: python, bash, for-loop, io, subprocess

I am attempting to call a bash script via the subprocess Popen function passes in a  for loop. My intent is that with each iteration, a new string **commit** from an array **out** is passed as an argument to the Popen command. The command invokes a bash script that outputs a text identified by the variable **commit** and greps certain lines from that particular text. However, I can't get the output to flush out in the Python for loop. Right now, only the grepped data from the final **commit** in **out** is being passed into my final data structure (a pandas dataframe).

```
accuracy_dictionary = {}
for commit in out:
    accuracy_dictionary.setdefault(commit, {})
    p2 = subprocess.Popen(['~/Desktop/find_accuracies.sh', commit], encoding='utf-8', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    outputstring = p2.stdout.read()
    # This part below is less critical to the problem at hand
    # I'm putting the data from each file in a dictionary
    for acc_type_line in outputstring.split('\n'):
        accuracy = acc_type_line.split(': ')
        if accuracy != ['']:
            acc_type = accuracy[0]
            value = accuracy[1]
            accuracy_dictionary[commit][acc_type] = float(value)

acc_data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(accuracy_dictionary).T
```

Here is the bash script that is being called:

"find_accuracies.sh":

```
#!/bin/sh

COMMIT=$1
git show $COMMIT:blahblahfolder/blahblah.txt | grep --line-buffered 'accuracy'
```

acc_data returns a dataframe of nrows=len(**out**) populated by unique **commit**s, but the **value** is the exact same for all rows for each **acc_type**

For example, my output looks like this:
[image]

How can I call the file "find_accuracies.sh" with the subprocess command and have it flush the unique values of each file for each commit?

Comment: Doesn't help your problem, but note that you are not calling a `bash` script since the header is `#!/bin/sh`, so you are calling `sh`, not `bash` - yes, there are huge differences, even if `sh` is linked to `bash`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/disable-output-buffering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this help addressing the immediate problem you're seeing: Here you should really use `communicate` with `subprocess.PIPE` as it waits for the command to finish and give give you all of its output:

```
outputstring = p2.communicate()[0]
```

You can also use convenient method like `check_output` to the same effect:

```
outputstring = subprocess.check_output(['~/Desktop/find_accuracies.sh', commit],
                                       encoding='utf-8', shell=True)
```

Or also in py3 use `run` should also do:

```
p2 = subprocess.run(['~/Desktop/find_accuracies.sh', commit],
                    encoding='utf-8', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
outputstring = p2.stdout
```

Now few more comments, hints and suggestions:

I am a little surprised it works for you as using `shell=True` and list of arguments [should](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) (see the paragraph starting with *"On POSIX with `shell=True`"*) make your `commit` argument of the underlying `sh` wrapped around your script call and not of the script itself. In any case you can (and I would suggest to) actually drop the `shell` and leave `HOME` resolution to python:

```
from pathlib import Path
executable = Path.home().joinpath('Desktop/find_accuracies.sh')

p2 = subprocess.run([executable, commit],
                    encoding='utf-8', stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
outputstring = p2.stdout
```

You can (or must for py <3.5) also use `os.path.expanduser('~/Desktop/find_accuracies.sh')` instead of `Path.home()` to get script `executable`. On the other hand for >=3.7 you could replace `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` with `capture_output=True`.

And last but not least. It seems a bit unnecessary to call a bash script (esp. double wrapped in `sh` call like in the original example) just to run `git` through `grep` when we already have a python script to process the information. I would actually try to run the corresponding `git` command directly getting the bulk of its output and process its output in the python script itself to get the bits of interest.